# titlesec troubles

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titlesec

I am working on a document that will consist of many sections and subsections.  I want to have a table of contents per section.  I am using `titlesec`, `titletoc` and `titleps`.

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, 
            linkcolor=blue, 
            filecolor=blue, 
            urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage[margin=15mm,
paperheight=15cm,paperwidth=13cm
]{geometry}
%for demonstation purposes, not contributing to MWE.

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%this has no apparent effect
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

%this causes near duplicated entries in the table of contents
% if a \clearpage is added
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{%\clearpage
\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}\label{First}

The section TOC:

\hfill\hrule\hfill

\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\hfill\hrule

\subsection{Sub1}

\section{Second}\label{Second Section}

The section TOC:

\hfill\hrule\hfill

\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\hfill\hrule

\subsection{Sub1}

\section{Second}\label{Third Section}

The section TOC:

\hfill\hrule\hfill

\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\hfill\hrule

\subsection{Sub1}

\end{document}
```

With this I have three issues:

1. If I add clearpage to the `\titleformat{section}` I get duplicated entries in the table of contents; if I add `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` it apparently has no effect.
2. The section table of contents contains information from prior or subsequent sections; I don't want that
3. I am not sure whether its related, there seems to be a `clearpage` after the `table of contents`; in this case I won't mind, but I might not want that in future. (It could be the `\sectionbreak`, but then why does it not work later on?)

Below is the rendered (`lualatex`) version(I don't know to shrink them to three in a row):
[image: Page1][image: Page2][image: Page3]

Comment: How do one shrink images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct loading order is

```
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

because `hyperref` redefines the sectioning and table of contents related commands, which is done also by the other three packages.

So if you load `hyperref` first, the three `titleX` packages redefine the commands based on `hyperref`'s redefinition of the standard ones. Chaos ensues.

For having a page break before every section, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

before `hyperref` and, after the `\titleformat{\section}...` command, add also

```
\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage}{}{}
```

Of course this will add a page break after the table of contents, if a section immediately follows. I don't think it makes sense to have a page break before all sections but not before the first one.

In order to have only the subsections in the partial table of contents, use

```
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
```

Comment: this solves the problem with the extraneous entries in the section toc.

Comment: @Louis You can't say `\clearpage` in `\titleformat`; I added a workaround for this; I addressed also the problem of having only subsections in the partial tocs.

Comment: I will accept you solution and also incorporate part of solution by @Thorstone Donig.  Yours cover most, the other one introduce something else: centralisng the section `TOC`'s which will a lot in the large document I'm working with.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to incorporate the partial ToC for the sections into their formatting. This is an approach for PDFLaTeX, but the relevant settings should also work with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  % option `pagestyles` loads »titleps«
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  breaklinks,
  colorlinks
}

\titleformat{name=\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}
[\normalsize\normalfont\vspace*{1pc}%
\hbox{\large\bfseries\contentsname}\vspace{6pt}\titlerule\vspace{3pt}
\startcontents
\printcontents{l}{2}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}\vspace{1pt}
\titlerule\vspace{1pc}\thispagestyle{plain}]

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}
[\thispagestyle{plain}]

\newpagestyle{front}{
  \sethead{\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
  \headrule
  \setfoot{}{}{}
}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead{\thesection\enspace\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
  \headrule
  \setfoot{}{}{}
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand*{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
% \assignpagestyle{\section}{plain}  % does not work

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{front}
  \tableofcontents

  \pagestyle{main}
  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
\end{document}
```

Further customization is of course possible.

---

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: This answer solves part of the problem.  I will try to incorporate the section tocs in my document, previously I could not get the assignstyles to work. I will accept the proposal by @egreg and still vote for this answer. (The `@` does not work now?)

Comment: @Louis: What does "assignstyles" mean in this context? For the page break before the sections you can use the approach by »[etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)« that is already mentioned in [egregs's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139312/1063).

Comment: From page 7 of the manual: `\assignpagestyle{[command]}{[pagestyle]}`.  As far as I can understand one can then assign a pagestyle to a chapter, section, subsection, part, etc.  I have not yet implemented that sucessfully.

Comment: @Louis: You should articulate things a bit more clearly. Of course I know this command, but not described with the terms you used. I can't see any defined page styles in your example. Which is the intended page style for section pages and which for all other pages?

Comment: I did not add that to the MWE as it would have been out of the scope.  I will at some stage, after I tried it ask a question specfic to that facility of `titlesec`.

Comment: @Louis: Then you should not have mentioned these styles. Nevertheless you can have a look at the updated example. Since `\assignpagestyle` somehow didn't work and only caused warnings, I incorporated e.g. the `plain` page style into the formatting of the section headings. And by the way, as you can see, a defined `\sectionbreak` works very well here.